# Unigine Heaven run directly from terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I think a lot of you would have benchmarked your Linux system using Unigine Heaven Benchmark 4.0. I know to run the it you can simply go to the Unigine Heaven folder and run the shell script file using "./heaven". And then the settings window will open in which you configure and click on "Run" button. What I want to do is from shell script. All I want is to know if there is some way I can modify the script so that it doesn't show the Settings window where I need to click "Run" but directly starts the Benchmarking using the default settings.

So can anyone please let me know the modification in the script so that I can just run the script and no intermediate settings window appears rather benchmarking starts directly..?

Also is there some keyboard shortcut to "Run" i.e. I press some combination of keys and benchmarking starts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The benchmark is *deliberately* hobbled so so cannot be scripted to run.
This was done to "encourage" people to buy the [pro](https://unigine.com/products/heaven/pro/) or [advanced](https://unigine.com/products/heaven/advanced/) licenses.

You *can* automate the mouse and keyboard to do things so you could fake it... But you have to monitor where things actually are. A lot of trial and error is required. Here's a little snippet that just clicks the Run button:

```
xdotool mousemove --window $(xdotool search heaven) 620 420 click 1
```

If you want to do anything serious though it seems likely that the $15 license will be the cheaper option (unless your time is worthless).